# Title parameters issues in Curl API Call in PHP

Tags: php

Am working with the following curl sample

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channel_points/custom_rewards?broadcaster_id=274637212' \
-H 'client-id: gx2pv4208cff0ig9ou7nk3riccffxt' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer vjxv3i0l4zxru966wsnwji51tmpkj2' \
-d '{
    "title":"game analysis 1v1",
    "cost":50000
}'
```

**here is my issue**

When I run the code below it displays error that Title parameter is missing. below is my effort so far

```
/*
$data_params= array(

"title" => 'demoning game1',
"cost" => 5000
);
*/

$data_params ='{
    "title":"game analysis101",
    "cost":5000
}';



$access_token ='my access token goes here';
$url ='https://api.twitch.tv/helix/channel_points/custom_rewards?broadcaster_id=14190064';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("client-id: my clientid goes here", "Authorization: Bearer $access_token")); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("client-id: my clientid goes here", "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",'Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

echo $output;
```

Comment: Try https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/